# Extract value from one data frame and add it to another data frame based on matching cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. I need to find the emails (column "customer_email") from data1   on data2 and extract the "observation" date corresponding to this email from data2) and add it to data1 on the column "date_first_order".

[data1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ju1C.png)

[data2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vUUe.png)

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to help you with programable tables instead of screenshots as it makes it harder to replicate, but this should give you something similar to what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer_Email' : ['1234', '5678', '90'],
    'Observation' : ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer_Email' : ['1234', '5678', '09'],
    'Observation' : ['01-01-2021', '01-02-2021', '01-03-2021']
})

df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, suffixes=('', '_df2'), on = 'Customer_Email')[['Customer_Email', 'Observation_df2']].rename({'Observation_df2': 'Observation'}, axis=1)
df_merge
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, extremely helpful... If i want to add more columns from data frame 1 or 2 to the newly created df_merge, how can I do it? ... I tried to, but i got this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: The `[['Customer_Email', 'Observation_df2']]` portion of the code limited the columns to only have those 2 columns in the merge. If you remove that then you will be able to have all the columns from both dataframes and you can limit it to whatever columns you would like.